# Why does this answer still have the "citation needed" notice?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question, citations, post-notice

This is regarding [this answer](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/34405/30596).

It was given a "citation needed" notice. The reason given in a comment was that the claim that her deputies were issuing licenses needed cited explicitly.

Since then, both [I](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/revisions/34405/2) and [a moderator](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/revisions/34405/3) edited the question to add quotes from the existing citations explicitly showing that she is complying with the order to allow same-sex marriage licenses from her office. It now includes three citations showing that Davis is not stopping her deputies from issuing licenses for same-sex marriages.

But the "citation needed" notice is still there. Is any additional citation required? If not, could you please remove the banner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer has to have at least 30 characters before it can be posted, so I couldn't just say "Done." like I wanted to.

Comment: It's [tag:status-completed] then?